# How to encrypt/decrypt url for the whole server?

Tags: php, security, urlencode, lighttpd

How can I encrypt and decrypt urls security reasons for the whole server? So

```
https://darkhelmet/pages/mainframe.php?eduId=28107&displayID=&theme=theme1&version=4.0.3&demo=
```

would be sent as

```
https://darkhelmet/pages/mainframe.php?eduId=Exy623&displayID=&theme=thdk8t&version=7hd44&demo=
```

So the real id that is 28107 will be encrypted to something like Exy623, something not meaningful to the user of the application. In case they change the id to let's say 28108 they will get data of some other user loaded on the page.

Could it be done so the solution is applied the the current application as a **new layer** on top of the application so there is **no need to change php files**?

using

- lighttpd-1.4.30
- php-5.3.6

Comment: Encrypt URL for a security reason?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here - what are you trying to hide from who?

Comment: I think is clear: he want to encrypt and decrypt part of a url, in a server layer without change a PHP file.

Comment: The solution will not allow users to view somebody else's data. Let's say if they change eduId in the url or using firebug in html.

Comment: Not sure why you were down-voted, it is a common security question. I'm up-voting

Comment: "In case they change the id to let's say 28108 they will get data of some other user loaded on the page." — You **cannot** depend on it being harder to guess ids to protect data. You **must** authenticate users and then authorise them for each request (by checking if the user is accessing data they own or are otherwise recorded in your model as being allowed to access when the page is requested).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify PHP file, you will need to intercept each HTTP request+response which can be done using reverse web proxy (you can also terminate your SSL here) which will relay HTTP request/resposne to your encryption+decryption code. This code can be totally independent of your app.